# How to prevent HTML email not ending up in junk folder in hotmail?

Tags: php, email, yii, hotmail

I have been sending an email to the user who signs up on my website. The email is correctly being sent to inbox folder in other services like gmail, yahoo but in case of hotmail sometimes it ends up in junk folder and sometimes it goes to inbox.

Below is my email code snippet from my registration code:

```
                $user->save();
                $activationUrl = Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl(true) . '/site/activateaccount?activation_key=' . $activationKey;
                $body = $this->renderPartial('accounts/registration_email', array('activationUrl' => $activationUrl), true);

                $subject = 'Please complete your signup';
                $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'From: Website Name<admin@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
                $headers.='Reply-To: admin@mydomain.com' . "\r\n";
                $headers.='Return-Path: admin@mydomain.com\r\n';

                if (mail($user->email, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
                    $this->redirect('registersuccess');
                }
```

Please note that the email I send is HTML email and in above code I have replaced website domain with mydomain.com for privacy and website actual name with Website Name.
I have tried changing email subject line, MIME-version and content type. 
Tried so many solutions already posted on SO here but no one makes it always go to inbox rather than junk.

My clinet has email account on hotmail so he wants that email to end up in inbox no matter what. Can something be done as sure shot solution? Does installing SSL on site domain solves this issue? Any other solution?

Comment: If there was a way to ensure an email always ended up in your inbox, then it would be full of spam because you can be that spammers would just use that technique.

Comment: Where the valid email senders go then? There is no way for non-spammers to send email to user inbox by ANY way?

Comment: There are plenty of posts out there that offer tips. But they are just that, tips. Nothing to ensure proper delivery always. hotmail has always been a pain IMO. It breaks down to avoid common words found in spam emails, ensure the server that sends the email resolves back to the same domain as the from address, don't get your site blacklisted for email and avoid lots of images. Just tips like that to make your email not look spammy. There are also email services that might help by digitally signing the email as not spam. But once again, not guaranteed or anything.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I think about hotmail. I even avoided spam words in my email. The same email once received in inbox for one recipient in hotmail goes to junk for other user. Hotmail is so pain. Bigger pain is to put this uncontrolled issue in my client's brain. He says other sites send emails in my inbox. Facepalm.

Comment: Over time it is likely that the emails will stop going to spam. The larger a site is, the more likely it can be trusted to send out good emails. Hotmail especially will send new/young sites into spam (just my opinion) because they are likely targets to send spam. On the other hand, the more people that mark an email as spam the more that site gets flagged as spam and vice versa. Just something to keep in mind. Also, using a pre-made software for stuff like forums, they can likely identify stuff like registration emails and know that they are not spam. It's all heuristics and past experience.

Comment: Yes. absolutely right. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Try adding the 5th additional parameter to the mail function. I've heard that it helps, but haven't tested and confirmed it myself since I always add it. Doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: Will give it a try to..@w3shivers..Thanks

Comment: @w3shivers what exactly would "$additionalParameters" do? is there a specific sendmail parameter that you would suggest?

Comment: according to the PHP manual you add it just after the headers in the mail function example: `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-femail.address@example.com"); `

Comment: @JonathanKuhn "It pass additional flags as command line options to the program configured to be used when sending mail" furthermore "The user that the webserver runs as should be added as a trusted user to the sendmail configuration to prevent a 'X-Warning' header from being added to the message when the envelope sender (-f) is set using this method. For sendmail users, this file is /etc/mail/trusted-users. " - [phpManual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: @w3shivers I guess I'm just used to setting up the sendmail parameters in php.ini. In that case, the additional parameters are not necessary as it is the same thing.

Comment: Yes. Jonathan. Also sending 5th paramater with "-femail.address@example.com") is helpful when From header is missing but it won't be of much help as I added that header already.